# How to clean the mold inside the A/C drain hose?

Tags: toyota, ac, corolla, hose, drain

I have a Toyota Corolla 2013. I know you can probably blow air or use a pen to clean the end of the A/C drain hose from underneath the car, but how can you clean the hose of the mold? Is there a safe chemical and entry point for the drain hose I can pour it through? Or do I have to replace the hose?

Comment: IF you pull back the carpet on the passenger side you'll see the HVAC housing and a tube that goes from the housing to the floor pan you can just pull it off.

Answer (score 2):

There is a product called BG Frig Fresh. It's made to eliminate mold and mildew from an AC.

There is a drain under the car, spray in from there, or go backwards and tap a hole in the box under the dash. Then spray into the hole (where the heater core and evap hose meet).